# nginx retornando erro nas rotas do Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, nginx

criei um container com php, mysql e o nginx para rodar uma aplicação de testes no laravel. Quando eu rodo o localhost:8080 ele entra na tela inicial, porém quando eu acesso o localhost:8080/qualquer-coisa ele me devolve um 500 Internal Server Error nginx

Dockerfile

```html
FROM wyveo/nginx-php-fpm:latest 
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/ngix/html
COPY . /usr/share/nginx
RUN chmod -R 775 /usr/share/nginx/storage/*
RUN ln -s public html
```

docker-compose.yaml

```html
version: '3'

services: 
  laravel-app: 
    build: .
    ports: 
      - "8080:80"  
    volumes: 
      - ./:/usr/share/nginx 
    networks: 
      - app-network
  mysql-app: 
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports: 
      - "3306:3306" 
    volumes: 
      - .docker/dbdata:/var/lib/mysql 
    environment: 
      MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: laravel
    networks: 
      - app-network
networks: 
  app-network: 
      driver: bridge
```

Rota para teste

```html
Route::get('/teste', function(){
   return view('teste');
});
```

Comment: Qual seria o erro salvo nos arquivos de log do Laravel ? Geralmente encontra-se em storage/logs/laravel.log

Comment: O erro é no PHP, no Laravel. O nginx tá funcionando corretamente e retornando erro 500 porque o problema é no backend / upstream.